# How to adjust the hours in working hours calendar

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to add the working hours of the employee with the following scenario: let's say the current date is: 2012-05-20 15:00, and the employee's normal working hours are 08:00-16:00, I want to add 0.25day (i.e. 2 hours) to this date and want to make sure it will not exceed the working hour's condition, so the expected result is 2012-05-21 09:00. Here is my code:

```java
private static final Set<LocalDate> FIXED_HOLIDAYS = new HashSet<>();

// Map of recurring annual holidays with their weekday occurrence (if applicable)
private static final Map<LocalDate, Integer> ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS = new HashMap<>();

// Working hours
private static final LocalTime WORKDAY_START = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
private static final LocalTime WORKDAY_END = LocalTime.of(16, 0);

// Utility methods

public static void addFixedHoliday(LocalDate date) {
    FIXED_HOLIDAYS.add(date);
}

public static void addAnnualHoliday(LocalDate date, int weekday) {
    ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.put(date, weekday);
}

public static boolean isWeekend(LocalDate date) {
    return date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
}

public static boolean isHoliday(LocalDate date) {
    return FIXED_HOLIDAYS.contains(date) || ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.containsKey(date) && date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() == ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.get(date);
}

public static LocalDateTime addWorkingDays(LocalDateTime startDateTime, double workDays) {
    LocalDate currentDate = startDateTime.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime currentTime = startDateTime.toLocalTime();

    Duration remainingDuration = Duration.ofHours((int) workDays).plusMinutes((int) ((workDays % 1) * 60));

    while (remainingDuration.getSeconds() > 0) {
        // Calculate work duration remaining in current day
        long durationUntilWorkdayEnd = Duration.between(currentTime, WORKDAY_END).getSeconds();
        Duration currentWorkDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(Math.min(remainingDuration.getSeconds(), durationUntilWorkdayEnd));

        // Advance date and time
        currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(isWeekend(currentDate) || isHoliday(currentDate) ? 1 : 0);

        // Handle starting from outside workday hours
        if (currentTime.isBefore(WORKDAY_START)) {
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START;
        }

        currentTime = currentTime.plus(currentWorkDuration);
        remainingDuration = remainingDuration.minus(currentWorkDuration);

        // Handle overflow into next day
        if (currentTime.isAfter(WORKDAY_END)) {
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START.plusMinutes(currentTime.getMinute() - WORKDAY_END.getMinute());
        }
    }

    return LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Your example with correct output
    LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 5, 24, 4, 0);
    double workDays = 0.5;
    LocalDateTime resultDateTime = addWorkingDays(startDateTime, workDays);
    System.out.println("Resulting datetime: " + resultDateTime); // Output: 2004-05-24T12:00
}
```

The current result is 2012-05-25T08:07, which is wrong as I expect a 09:07 in the time. Can someone suggest how I can add or remove the number of hours/days within the working hours duration?

--------------- Junit test cases--------------

```java
@Test
void addWorkingDaysTestDecimalValueCrossDayEarlyMorning() {
    // Input: 24-05-2004 04:00, Add 0.5 working days, o Expected Output: 24-05-2004 12:00
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 04, 0);
    BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5);
    // When
    LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
    // Then
    assertThat(result)
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 12, 0));
}

@Test
void addWorkingDaysTest44() {
    // Input: 24-05-2004 19:03, Add 44.723656 working days, o Expected Output: 27-07-2004 13:47
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 19, 03);
    BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(44.723656);
    // When
    LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
    // Then
    assertThat(result)
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 07, 27, 13, 47));
}

@Test
void addWorkingDaysTest6() {
    // Input: 24-05-2004 08:03, Add 12.782709 working days, o Expected Output: 10-06-2004 14:18
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 8, 03);
    BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(12.782709);
    // When
    LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
    // Then
    assertThat(result)
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 06, 10, 14, 18));
}

@Test
void addWorkingDaysTest8() {
    // Input: 24-05-2004 07:03, Add 8.276628  working days, o Expected Output: 04-06-2004 10:12
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 07, 03);
    BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(8.276628 );
    // When
    LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
    // Then
    assertThat(result)
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 06, 04, 10, 12));
}
```

Comment: *...and want to make sure it will not exceed the working hour's condition...* You don't say what that condition is?

Comment: Sorry, I mean need to adjust the time b/w the working hours( 08:00-16:00). for example, the current date is 2012-05-24T15:00, so we need to add 2 hours in this date and time, only 1 hour is remaining from today's working hour so we add 1 hour in the current day and the remaining 1 hour would be the next working day which starts from 08:00 so the end result date would be 2012-05-25T09:00

Comment: OK. The first thing I'd say is to avoid decimals - that's going to end in tears

Comment: I agree, but this is a requirement as I need to add or subtract the days based on like 0.5 day(Half working day), 0.25(2 hrs based on 8 working hrs), etc. It make the logic very easy otherwise I need to deal both the hours and days separately.

Comment: Can  `double workDays` be greater than 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it can be greater than 1

Comment: @user565 did you change the code? The current code is very different from the one you initially posted

Comment: it is a similar code but I added the full version.

Comment: When I ran the code in your question it printed: `Resulting datetime: 2004-05-24T08:30` so I don't understand why you wrote (in your question): _The current result is 2012-05-25T08:07_. According to the code in your question your start time is 4 am and you want to add 4 hours to that (i.e. 0.5 working days). As I understand your requirements, that means you essentially want to add 4 hours to 8 am so the result should be: 2012-05-04 12:00. What am I missing?

Comment: Also I don't understand this part of your code: `(workDays % 1)`. The result of that will **always** be `workDays`, won't it?

Comment: Sorry, I added a different example in the complete code. Yes, I am trying to find the same result like if the time is 4am, adding 0.5day(04 hours) count from 08:00 and the end result would be same day 12:00

Comment: @Abra `someDoubleNumber % 1` is a standard way of getting the fractional part of `someDoubleNumber` - in this case, it gets the number of minutes (without hours).

Comment: @user565 If your use case is made of only quarters of work days (es. 1/4 of workday, 2/4 of workday, etc), I think that using BigDecimal is a bit over engineering, I would rather change the signature to accept an integer (number of quarter of days to add) or put some limitation on the input (maybe using an enum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. It basically uses the same algorithm as the code in your question, subtracting the amount of work hours in a day from the supplied `workDays` parameter (to method `addWorkingDays`) until the value reaches zero.

Note that in your question, there are no "fixed holidays" and no "annual holidays". When I ran the below code with your test data, each result was exactly one day less than your expected value (as written in your question). Then I saw that May 31, 2004 was a [public holiday in USA](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?country=1&year=2004) so when I added that to "fixed holidays" I got exactly the same results as your expected results. I also noted that July 5, 2004 was also a public holiday since July 4, 2004 was a Sunday. Hence I also added that to "fixed holidays" and as a result your expected result for your first test case is wrong.

I admit that I didn't understand how to factor in "annual holidays" so I ignored that.

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class WorkHour {
    private static final Set<LocalDate> FIXED_HOLIDAYS = new HashSet<>();

    // Map of recurring annual holidays with their weekday occurrence (if applicable)
    private static final Map<LocalDate, Integer> ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS = new HashMap<>();

    // Working hours
    private static final LocalTime WORKDAY_START = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
    private static final LocalTime WORKDAY_END = LocalTime.of(16, 0);

    // Utility methods

    public static void addFixedHoliday(LocalDate date) {
        FIXED_HOLIDAYS.add(date);
    }

    public static void addAnnualHoliday(LocalDate date, int weekday) {
        ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.put(date, weekday);
    }

    public static LocalDateTime adjustHoliday(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
        while (FIXED_HOLIDAYS.contains(ld)) {
            ldt = ldt.plusDays(1);
            ld = ld.plusDays(1);
            ldt = ldt.withHour(8).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
        }
        return ldt;
    }

    public static LocalDateTime adjustWeekend(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        DayOfWeek weekday = ldt.getDayOfWeek();
        switch (weekday) {
            case SATURDAY:
                ldt = ldt.plusDays(1);
            case SUNDAY:
                ldt = ldt.plusDays(1);
                ldt = ldt.withHour(8).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return ldt;
    }

    public static boolean isHoliday(LocalDate date) {
        return FIXED_HOLIDAYS.contains(date)      ||
               ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.containsKey(date)  &&
               date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() == ANNUAL_HOLIDAYS.get(date);
    }

    public static LocalDateTime addWorkingDays(LocalDateTime startDateTime, double workDays) {
        LocalDate currentDate = startDateTime.toLocalDate();
        LocalTime currentTime = startDateTime.toLocalTime();

        // Handle starting from outside workday hours
        if (currentTime.isBefore(WORKDAY_START)) {
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START;
        }
        if (currentTime.isAfter(WORKDAY_END)) {
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START;
            currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
        }
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
        ldt = adjustWeekend(ldt);
        ldt = adjustHoliday(ldt);
        currentDate = ldt.toLocalDate();
        currentTime = ldt.toLocalTime();
        double totalHours = workDays * 8;
        long whole = (long) totalHours;
        double fraction = totalHours - whole;
        long wholeSeconds = whole * 60 * 60;
        long fractionSeconds = (long) (fraction * 60 * 60);
        long totalSeconds = wholeSeconds + fractionSeconds;
        while (totalSeconds > 0) {
            // Calculate work duration remaining in current day
            long durationUntilWorkdayEnd = Duration.between(currentTime, WORKDAY_END).getSeconds();
            ldt = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
            if (durationUntilWorkdayEnd > totalSeconds) {
                ldt = ldt.plusSeconds(totalSeconds);
                totalSeconds = 0;
            }
            else {
                ldt = ldt.plusSeconds(durationUntilWorkdayEnd);
                totalSeconds -= durationUntilWorkdayEnd;
            }
            currentDate = ldt.toLocalDate();
            currentTime = ldt.toLocalTime();
            if (totalSeconds > 0) {
                currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
                currentTime = WORKDAY_START;
                ldt = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
                ldt = adjustWeekend(ldt);
                ldt = adjustHoliday(ldt);
                currentDate = ldt.toLocalDate();
                currentTime = ldt.toLocalTime();
            }
        }
        return LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addFixedHoliday(LocalDate.of(2004, 5, 31));
        addFixedHoliday(LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 5));
        // Input: 24-05-2004 19:03, Add 44.723656 working days, o Expected Output: 27-07-2004 13:47
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 5, 24, 19, 3);
        double workDays = 44.723656;
        LocalDateTime resultDateTime = addWorkingDays(startDateTime, workDays);
        System.out.println("Resulting datetime: " + resultDateTime);
        // Input: 24-05-2004 04:00, Add 0.5       working days, o Expected Output: 24-05-2004 12:00
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 5, 24, 4, 0);
        workDays = 0.5;
        resultDateTime = addWorkingDays(startDateTime, workDays);
        System.out.println("Resulting datetime: " + resultDateTime);
        // Input: 24-05-2004 08:03, Add 12.782709 working days, o Expected Output: 10-06-2004 14:18
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 5, 24, 8, 3);
        workDays = 12.782709;
        resultDateTime = addWorkingDays(startDateTime, workDays);
        System.out.println("Resulting datetime: " + resultDateTime);
        // Input: 24-05-2004 07:03, Add 8.276628  working days, o Expected Output: 04-06-2004 10:12
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 5, 24, 7, 3);
        workDays = 8.276628;
        resultDateTime = addWorkingDays(startDateTime, workDays);
        System.out.println("Resulting datetime: " + resultDateTime);
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code:

```
Resulting datetime: 2004-07-28T13:47:21
Resulting datetime: 2004-05-24T12:00
Resulting datetime: 2004-06-10T14:18:42
Resulting datetime: 2004-06-04T10:12:46
```

Comment: Abra: all the test cases are working except the first one. (2004, 5, 24, 19, 3) with workDays = 44.723656; should be like (2004, 7, 27, 13, 47) but using your code it is showing the date (2004, 7, 28, 13, 47). Any idea of this one?

Comment: @user565 did you not read what I wrote (in my answer) regarding the public holiday on July 5, 2004? Just remove this line of code in my answer (or make it a comment): `addFixedHoliday(LocalDate.of(2004, 7, 5));`

Comment: thanks, by the way, is it possible to subtract the working days using the same method? how?

Answer (score 3):

This should work :) (assuming that a shift is 8 hours long)

EDIT: refactored a little bit

```
public static LocalDateTime addWorkingDays(LocalDateTime startDateTime, double workDays) {
    LocalDate currentDate = startDateTime.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime currentTime = startDateTime.toLocalTime();
    int currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinute();

    int hoursToAdd = (int) (workDays * 8);

    while (hoursToAdd > 0) {
        if (!isWorkingDay(currentDate)) {
            currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START.plusMinutes(currentMinutes);
            continue;
        }
        if (currentTime.plusHours(1).isAfter(WORKDAY_END)) {
            currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
            currentTime = WORKDAY_START.plusMinutes(currentMinutes);
            continue;
        }
        currentTime = currentTime.plusHours(1);
        hoursToAdd--;
    }

    return LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, currentTime);
}

public static boolean isWorkingDay(LocalDate date) {
    return !(isWeekend(date) || isHoliday(date));
}
```

Please keep in mind that this code is based on the use case of adding multiple of quarters of day (e.g. 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5) and it may not work for particular double inputs

Comment: don't work, I made 3 unit test, all failed: // Given 2024.2.21 15:00 (Wednesday), plus 5 working days, expected 2024.2.28 15:00 // Given 2024.2.21 15:00 (Wednesday), plus 5 working days, expected 2024.2.28 15:00 // Given 2024.2.21 10:00 (Wednesday), plus 2.5 working days, expected 2024.2.23 14:00 (Friday)

Comment: I've made a fix: now if isWeekend or isHoliday do hoursToAdd--. Could you try now?

Comment: still fail all 3 !

Comment: Oops, I didn't manage well the weekends and holidays. I tried your unit test and now are all green :)

Comment: test are on my answer, you can try on your own !

Comment: @Stefano Riffaldi I have added a few old date test cases in my question that seem to be failing. Is there any reason for them not to work on old dates?

Comment: I like this version more because it's cleaner than Stefano's answer and it does fulfil the initial requirement of `double` parameter for `addWorkingDays` method

Comment: @user565 addWorkingDaysTest6 is wrong, expectaion is on 2004.06.09 not 10 !

Comment: @pochopsp Too bad it doesn't work. try my addWorkingDaysTestCrossWeekend test on this solution, you'll see

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi I updated my code 1 hour ago, now your addWorkingDaysTestCrossWeekend test works :)

Comment: I created a addWorkingDays version with double workDays parameter as Bezkup suggested, but it is still not working on all the test cases that I have added in my question.

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi I tried the test you mentioned, it works with Bezkup 's code

Comment: @user565 which one doesn't work? addWorkingDaysTestCrossWeekendWithHoliday?

Comment: @Bezkup All of them which I have added to my question.

Comment: how? I've copied those tests and all of them (except the one I wrote before, but I have some doubts about it) pass flawlessly

Comment: That's very strange, for example, this one is giving an error:
   LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2004, 05, 24, 07, 03);
   BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(8.276628 );

LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result)
                .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 06, 04, 10, 12));


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
expected: 2004-06-04T10:12 (java.time.LocalDateTime)
 but was: 2004-06-03T09:15 (java.time.LocalDateTime)

Comment: Wait, are you using @StefanoRiffaldi's code? Because mine uses double and not BigDecimal

Comment: Bezkup: both using double and BigDecimal none of the above added test cases are working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256951/discussion-between-bezkup-and-user565).

Answer (score 0):

That's my way, using BigDecimal (I don't like using double couse of imprecision)

Works very good

```
package org.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * StackOverflow Question:
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033477/11289119">How to adjust the hours in working hours calendar</a>
 *
 * @author stefano-riffaldi
 */
public class WorkingHoursService {
    private final Collection<LocalDate> holidays;
    private final LocalTime workdayStart;
    private final LocalTime workdayEnd;

    public WorkingHoursService() {
        this(Collections.emptySet(), LocalTime.of(8, 0), LocalTime.of(16, 0));
    }

    public WorkingHoursService(Collection<LocalDate> holidays, LocalTime workdayStart, LocalTime workdayEnd) {
        this.holidays = holidays;
        this.workdayStart = workdayStart;
        this.workdayEnd = workdayEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Given a LocalDateTime, add the number of working days as decimal number, make sure it will not exceed the working hour's conditions that is:
     * employee's working hours are 8:00 am to 16:00 pm
     * employee's do not work in the weekends
     * employee's do not work on holidays
     *
     * @param startDateTime
     * @param workDays
     * @return
     */
    public LocalDateTime addWorkingDays(LocalDateTime startDateTime, BigDecimal workDays) {
        // get integer part of workDays
        BigDecimal days = workDays.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        // get decimal part to get hours extra, using minutes to be precise
        BigDecimal minutes = workDays.subtract(days).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(8 * 60));
        LocalDateTime plussed = startDateTime.plusMinutes(minutes.intValue());
        // Check if working time exceeds 8:00 am to 16:00 pm
        long remainingMinutes = Duration.between(workdayEnd, plussed.toLocalTime()).toMinutes();
        // if that is the case, add 1 day and remaining minutes
        if (remainingMinutes > 0) {
            plussed = LocalDateTime.of(plussed.toLocalDate().plusDays(1), workdayStart.plusMinutes(remainingMinutes));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < days.intValue(); i++) {
            // if plussed is a holiday or weekend, add 1 day 'for free'
            while (isWeekend(plussed.toLocalDate()) || isHoliday(plussed.toLocalDate())) {
                plussed = plussed.plusDays(1);
            }
            plussed = plussed.plusDays(1);
        }
        return plussed;
    }

    private boolean isHoliday(LocalDate startDate) {
        return holidays.contains(startDate);
    }

    private boolean isWeekend(LocalDate startDate) {
        return startDate.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY || startDate.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY;
    }
}
```

test here

```
package org.example.test;

import org.assertj.core.api.Condition;
import org.example.WorkingHoursService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;

import static java.time.DayOfWeek.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class WorkingHoursServiceTest {
    private final WorkingHoursService service = new WorkingHoursService(
            List.of(
                    LocalDate.of(2024, 1, 1), // First of Year
                    LocalDate.of(2024, 3, 31), // Ester day
                    LocalDate.of(2024, 4, 1), // Easter Monday
                    LocalDate.of(2024, 12, 25) // Christmas
            ),
            LocalTime.of(8, 0), // start working day
            LocalTime.of(16, 0) // end working day
    );

    private Condition<? super LocalDateTime> dayOfTheWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
        return new Condition<>(localDateTime -> localDateTime.getDayOfWeek() == dayOfWeek, "day of the week " + dayOfWeek);
    }

    @Test
    void addWorkingDaysTest() {
        // Given 2024.2.21 15:00 (Wednesday), plus 1 working day, expected 2024.2.22 15:00
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 21, 15, 0);
        BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
        // When
        LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(start.plusDays(1));
    }

    @Test
    void addWorkingDaysTestCrossWeekend() {
        // Given 2024.2.21 15:00 (Wednesday), plus 5 working days, expected 2024.2.28 15:00
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 21, 15, 0);
        BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
        // When
        LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result)
                .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 28, 15, 0))
                .is(dayOfTheWeek(WEDNESDAY));
    }

    @Test
    void addWorkingDaysTestCrossWeekendWithHoliday() {
        // Given 2024.3.28 8:00 (Wednesday), plus 5 working days, expected 2024.4.8 8:00 (Friday) because of the weekend and Ester Monday
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 3, 28, 8, 0);
        BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
        // When
        LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result)
                .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 4, 5, 8, 0))
                .is(dayOfTheWeek(FRIDAY));
    }

    @Test
    void addWorkingDaysTestDecimalValue() {
        // Given 2024.2.21 10:00 (Wednesday), plus 2.5 working days, expected 2024.2.23 14:00 (Friday)
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 21, 10, 0);
        BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5);
        // When
        LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result)
                .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 23, 14, 0))
                .is(dayOfTheWeek(FRIDAY));
    }

    @Test
    void addWorkingDaysTestDecimalValueCrossDay() {
        // Given 2024.2.21 14:00 (Wednesday), plus 0.5 working days (4 h), expected 2024.2.22 10:00 (Thursday)
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 21, 14, 0);
        BigDecimal workDays = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5);
        // When
        LocalDateTime result = service.addWorkingDays(start, workDays);
        // Then
        assertThat(result)
                .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2024, 2, 22, 10, 0))
                .is(dayOfTheWeek(THURSDAY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Stefano Riffaldi All of your test cases are working with the above code, but the problem is that my test cases which I added to my question are all failing.